# Need help with RFI issue

Tags: rfi

I am running an IMax 2000 antenna with a President Lincoln 2 plus radio. I am having a lot of issues with ac noise coming through my antenna. I ruled out the noise coming from my home by turning off my main breakers and running my radio on a battery and noise was still present. Had my power company come and they fixed 4 areas around me that noise was found.The noise level is less but still showing up at S-5. I would like to know what type of RFI filter would help quiet the remaining noise. I have been checking into an MFJ-915 filter but not sure if it would work. 73s K2JEG

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't filter out in band noise very effectively.  You need to find the source of the noise and fix it.  Put your radio on a battery to make it portable, and use a short piece of wire as an antenna, and walk around and see if you can find the source.  If you can't hear the noise, use a longer wire.   A loop antenna is directional and is a big help for this.  Use it to get a bearing from a couple of different locations to triangulate where the source is.  Lamp dimmers and touch lamps are big suspects in your neighbor's house. Noise from these can couple into power lines and radiate quite a ways, making it seem like the noise comes from everywhere near AC wires.